# How do I make a <select> tag toggle hide a different <select> tag in HTML-CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For simplicity's sakes, I'll [link](https://codepen.io/msSeattle/pen/OJmbwQa?editors=1111) the project.

I've been sat staring at this canvas for well over 10 hours, I'm nowhere near an experienced developer so I'm fine with accepting that I'm probably overlooking something, but at this point I'm completely stumped.

I'm trying to make like (HTML 10) call a JS function(hiddenVancian()) that toggles the visibility of a  (HTML: 56) with another nested  tag.

Thank you for your time!

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /* For each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item: */
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box: */
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);

var systemValue = document.getElementById("systemChoice")
var hideElement = document.getElementById("vancianSelect").style.visibility = "hidden";
var showElement = systemValue = document.getElementById("vancianSelect").value
function hiddenVancian() {
  systemValue == 1 ? hideElement : showElement;
}
```

```css
.h1 {
  color: black;
}

.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none;
  /* Hide original SELECT element: */
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.select-selected::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid #4353cc;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  background-color: #4353cc;
}

.select-selected.select-arrow-active::after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #4353cc;
  border-color: #2231a3 #4353cc rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: #4353cc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: transparent);
}
```

```html
<head>
<body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
  <h1>
    Spheres of Might & Power Character Tool
  </h1>
  <p>This is an attempt at creating a coherent character creation tool not all too unlike that of DnDBeyonds tool.</p>
  
  <div class="custom-select"  style="width: 200px;">
    <select id="systemChoice" onchange="hiddenVancian()" console.log(val)>
    <option value="0">Select System</option>
      <option value="1">Vancian</option>
      <option value="2">Pure Spheres 5e</option>
      <option value="3">Spheres 5e Classes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- spacing -->
  <div name="raceSelect" class="custom-select" style="width:200px">
    <select>
      <option value="0">Select Race:</option>
      <option value="1">Human</option>
      <option value="1.5">Human Variant</option>
      <option value="2">Dark Elf</option>
      <option value="2.1">Eladrin Elf</option>
      <option value="2.2">High Elf</option>
      <option value="2.3">Wood Elf</option>
      <option value="3">Hill Dwarf</option>
      <option value="3.1">Mountain Dwarf</option>
      <option value="4">Dragonborn</option>
      <option value="5.1">Lightfoot Halfling</option>
      <option value="5.2">Stout Halfling</option>
      <option value="6">Half-Orc</option>
      <option value="7">Tiefling</option>
      <option value="8">Aasimar</option>
    </select>
  </div> <br>
  <!-- Should be hidden unless Vancian is selected -->
  <div id="vancianSelect" class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
    <select>
      <option value="0">Select Class:</option>
      <option value="1">Artificer</option>
      <option value="2">Barbarian</option>
      <option value="3">Bard</option>
      <option value="4">Cleric</option>
      <option value="5">Druid</option>
      <option value="6">Fighter</option>
      <option value="7">Monk</option>
      <option value="8">Paladin</option>
      <option value="9">Ranger</option>
      <option value="10">Rogue</option>
      <option value="11">Sorcerer</option>
      <option value="12">Warlock</option>
      <option value="13">Wizard</option>
    </select>
  </div> <br>
  <!-- Should be hidden unless SpheresPure is selected-->
  <div name="levelSelect" class="custom-select" style="width:200px">
    <select>
      <option value="1">Level: </option>
      <option value="1">Level: 1</option>
      <option value="2">Level: 2</option>
      <option value="3">Level: 3</option>
      <option value="4">Level: 4</option>
      <option value="5">Level: 5</option>
      <option value="6">Level: 6</option>
      <option value="7">Level: 7</option>
      <option value="8">Level: 8</option>
      <option value="9">Level: 9</option>
      <option value="10">Level: 10</option>
      <option value="11">Level: 11</option>
      <option value="12">Level: 12</option>
      <option value="13">Level: 13</option>
      <option value="14">Level: 14</option>
      <option value="15">Level: 15</option>
      <option value="16">Level: 16</option>
      <option value="17">Level: 17</option>
      <option value="18">Level: 18</option>
      <option value="19">Level: 19</option>
      <option value="20">Level: 20</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</body>

<article>
  <h2>
    Character Sheet:
  </h2>
  Character Name:
  <input style="text">

  This is where I want it to print the selected Race and Class from selections above:

</article>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi. Tell me if I'm wrong. You are trying to automatically open race menu dropdown when you select something from system options??

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: @R.Kazmi Hi! So what I'm trying to do is have the System Options selection show and hide its respective options;
So if I select Vancian in the System Options, I want *only* the Vancian dropdown menu to show up, and if I select Sphere Pure, I want it to automatically hide the Vancian dropdown and show Sphere Pure instead.

Comment: Try making a simplified version of your code, for example with just a few options on the select and take out any code which isn't relevant. You may find this helps you solve the problem yourself, but if not it will help us help you.